# Calculating an exponentially increasing vector of points in a test and measure system

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, exponential-function, applications

My application is setting and measuring current and voltage in a physical system with a software algorithm. Given these parameters: `min`, `max` , and `n`, I need to calculate a set of `n` values from `min` to `max` (inclusive) with a dense distribution of values close to `min`, with decreasing distribution density (larger step size) approaching `max`.

A *similar* distribution could be obtained by `f(i) = f(i-1) * k`, with k > 1. However, this doesn't provide for control over number of values `n`, but one could start from `min` and stop before or near `max`, not guaranteeing the inclusion of `max`. This curve should appear linear when plotted in log scale.

I am looking for a function `f(min, max, n, i)` for some integral index `i` from 1 to `n` which would produce these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your idea $f(i)=f(i-1)*k$ just fine.  If you want $n$ values, (hence $n-1$ factors of $k$) you need $k=\left(\frac {\max}{\min}\right)^{\frac 1{n-1}}$  Now $f(1)=\min, f(n)=\max, f(i)=\min\cdot k^{i-1}$